# ¿Por qué no se muestra el icono ni la imagen en esta GUI de JAVA?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo un proyecto de JAVA (estoy comenzando a estudiarlo) en el que tengo un paquete (aqgui) y dentro todos los archivos JAVA que tengo. Concretamente estoy trabajando en uno llamado "FinalProyect.java".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El motivo de poner la imagen no es enseñar el código, sino que se vea la estructura de cómo está montado dicho proyecto. Bien. Una vez visto que tengo la carpeta "images" dentro del "src" del proyecto, me gustaría saber si, estando correcto todo el código que muestro en la imagen, por qué no se ve ni el icono ni la imagen de coca-cola en dicha GUI:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo el código para su mejor lectura:

```
package aqgui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FinalProyect extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private JTextField textfield1;
    private JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4;
    private JButton boton1;
    
    public FinalProyect() {
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Bienvenido");
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));
        setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/icon.png")).getImage());
        
        ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon("/images/logo-coca.png");
        label1 = new JLabel(imagen);
        label1.setBounds(25,15,300,150);
        add(label1);
        
        label2 = new JLabel("Sistema de Control Vacacional");
        label2.setBounds(35,135,300,30);
        label2.setFont(new Font("Andale Mono", 3, 18));
        label2.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
        add(label2);
        
        label3 = new JLabel("Ingrese su nombre");
        label3.setBounds(45,212,200,30);
        label3.setFont(new Font("Andale Mono", 3, 12));
        label3.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
        add(label3);
        
        label4 = new JLabel("© 2017 The Coca-Cola Company");
        label4.setBounds(85,375,300,30);
        label4.setFont(new Font("Andale Mono", 3, 12));
        label4.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
        add(label4);
        
        textfield1 = new JTextField();
        textfield1.setBounds(45,240,255,25);
        textfield1.setBackground(new Color(224,224,224));
        textfield1.setFont(new Font("Andale Mono", 3, 14));
        textfield1.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
        add(textfield1);
        
        boton1 = new JButton("Ingresar");
        boton1.setBounds(125,280,100,30);
        boton1.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        boton1.setFont(new Font("Andale Mono", 1, 14));
        boton1.setForeground(new Color(255,0,0));
        boton1.addActionListener(this);
        add(boton1);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == boton1) {
            
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FinalProyect ventanabienvenida = new FinalProyect();
        
        ventanabienvenida.setBounds(0,0,350,450);
        ventanabienvenida.setVisible(true);
        ventanabienvenida.setResizable(false);
        ventanabienvenida.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

¿Cuál podría ser el error por el cual no consigo ver las imágenes?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

`this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/icon.png")).getImage());`

**No** utilices **setBounds()** para cambiar el tamaño del JLabel1 . Usa un [administrador de diseño](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) y así no te preocuparás por hacer eso manualmente.

Comment: Nada, sigue igual